# Parse HTTP-style key-value pairs into java.util.HashMap

Tags: java, android, parsing, hashmap, key-value

I am consuming a web service which presents its responses as an HTTP-style list of key-value pairs. I want to parse them into a HashMap. I do not want to write the parser. I want to revise my current hackish solution, a `string.split("&")` followed by a series of `string.split("=")` calls with logic interspersed.

Does anybody out there in SO-land know of references to a library that will do this? I browsed around in Apache and javax but didn't see much. I'm doing this in Android.

A simple example of a response is:

```
result=success&id=8a8d3c30-e184-11e1-9b23-0800200c9a66&name=wahooooooo
```

The ideal function:

```
public HashMap<String, String> parse(InputStream in);
```

Comment: have you tried using HttpComponents .. hc.apache.org

Comment: why do you want to add a complete Library for such a simple task? You are right about replacing string.split (which uses regex) as it is rather slow, though.

Comment: @kw4nta - I would be happy with just the function I describe above, or something similar.

Comment: Don't forget that parameter names in an HTTP URL query may be repeated and if that happens and you put them in any kind of map, you'll lose data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have apache libraries, you can use URLEncodedUtils class like this :

```
    HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String query = "result=success&id=8a8d3c30-e184-11e1-9b23-0800200c9a66&name=wahooooooo";
    List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(query, Charset.defaultCharset());
    for (NameValuePair nameValuePair : params) {
        parameters.put(nameValuePair.getName(), nameValuePair.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: Excellent. You and JAVAGeek both rock. You also both need some reputation, but you're lower so I'll give you the accept.

Comment: The library requires that I send it a URI, not a string. But the response from the server is not properly URI-encoded. So I'm out of luck with these solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UrlEncodedUtils](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

just invoke `URLEncodedUtils.parse(yourString,Charset.forName("UTF-8")).`

and you will get a `List<NameValuePair>` containing name and value associated elements.

see this : [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/)

[here](http://rapidpaste.com/s/73349eb5bb) is a simple program

Comment: Excellent! You and mabroukb both gave essentially the same answer, and I am perfectly happy with a List of NVPs. I upvoted both but will accept his because his rep is lower. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered but here is an alternative to `URLEncodedUtils`

```
public static HashMap<String, String> getQueryString(String url) {
    Uri uri= Uri.parse(url);

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String paramName : uri.getQueryParameterNames()) {
        if (paramName != null) {
            String paramValue = uri.getQueryParameter(paramName);
            if (paramValue != null) {
                map.put(paramName, paramValue);
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```